# Calling umount -l against USB device mount, generates 'unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty' warning/error?

Tags: usb-drive

Calling umount -l against USB device mount, generates 'unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty' warning/error?

I have a udev rule that runs a given script for add and remove events.  The add script does a mount for the usb drive, no issues.  The remove script works, but when I call umount -l against the USB drive (formatted as FAT) generates the above noted warning/error.

Moreover, calling eject apparently aborts the script, and the mount point is never removed with the (failed) eject call.

So this is a catch-22, umount -l works but is not clean (apparently) but eject aborts the actual bash script.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean no details?  I am asking if anyone else has been having issues with eject cli command.  And now I understand why people say that stack exchange is not a great place to ask questions.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using a lazy unmount rather than a normal unmount?  Sharing the problem script (or a truncated version of it) would help.

Comment: That is a good question... was using-l or lazy unmount because it was noted elsewhere that it was 'better' method to allow unmount.  But given USB is applicable here, you want an explicit commit of data, i.e. strong sync before removal.  The other quirky thing is some USB disks generate the warning some don't, using various makes and models, enclosures, etc.  Which could all come down to a timing issue of last data commit to device.